# SSIS Multicast - executing in a specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, multicast

I have an SSIS MULTICAST object that splits my flow into 2 paths.

1st path: i need to update a row;
2nd path: I need to insert a row.

Basically, I am implementing SCD TYPE2 data in SSIS without using SCD wizard. So after I have identified the record that has been changed in the source data, i need the '1st path' to expire that record while the '2nd path' to insert the changed record in the destination table.

I need a way to make 2nd path wait until the 1st path has finished. (otherwise, the 1st path will also update the newly inserted row by the 2nd path).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the "conditional split" component?

Comment: Honestly, make life easier on yourself - stage the updates to a persistent physical table and then have an Execute SQL Task fire after the dataflow. Meagan has a great writeup on it at [Demystifying the Type 2 Slowly Changing Dimension](https://datasavvy.me/2015/12/20/demystifying-the-type-2-slowly-changing-dimension-with-biml/)  You don't have to do the Biml, but her pictures ought to explain enough. The logic of hashing historical and change keys is worth its weight in gold-bits.

Answer (score 0):

Multicast is parallel operation, so you cannot make one path to wait for another.

So, What you need to do is, temporarily store the data in memory and process them later to insert into the destination (for SCD Type 2).

For temporarily storing the data, you have some options:

- Temporary tables (Use RetainSameConnection = true), so that session context is maintained. From temporary tables, you can load to final table. [Temporary tables Retain Same Connection](http://www.sqlerudition.com/what-is-the-retainsameconnection-property-of-oledb-connection-in-ssis/)
- Recordset destination (It is in-memory object). From the record set destination, you can load to final table in a Dataflow task or in a script task. [RecordSet destination in Dataflow task](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/20/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-data-flow-source/)
- Raw file destination (It is storing the data in the native format and easily can be reused) [Raw file destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/raw-file-destination?view=sql-server-ver15)